# active record to hash inside itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, activerecord, hash

So this is a bit of a silly one and is more lack of programming knowledge rather than anything ruby or rails specific.

If i wanted to turn an ordinary class into hash its not so bad. I already have one:

```
class CustomRequest
  require 'json'
  require 'net/http'
  attr_accessor :url, :depth, :status

  def initialize(url,depth)
    @url = url
    @depth = depth
  end

  def make_me_hash_and_send

    @myReq = {:url => @url, :depth =>@depth}
    myJsonReq = @myReq
    puts myJsonReq

    res = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://127.0.0.1:3008/user_requests/add.json'),
    myJsonReq)

  end
end
```

Simply generates the hash from the internal variables that are passed in the constructor. I want to do the same for active record but the abstractness of it isn't making it easy.

Lets say I have this class

```
def  turn_my_insides_to_hash
#How do I take the actual record variables 
# nd generate a hash from them.
#Is it something like

@myHash = {:myString = self.myString
  :myInt => self.myInt }

end
```

I may be looking at this the wrong way. I know Outside of the class I could simply say

```
@x = Result.find(passed_id).to_hash
```

and then do what I want to it. But I would rather call something liks

```
@x = Result.send
```

(which turns the result's variables into hash and sends them)
I already have the send part, just need to know how to turn variables into hash from inside class.

Comment: @myHash = self::attributes
    puts YAML::dump(@myHash)

Comment: first person to answer with that I'll mark as correct. I was referencing each parameter and wasn't aware attributes even existed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try use JSON instead of YAML:

```
Result.find(passed_id).to_json
```

or

```
Result.find(passed_id).attributes.to_json
```

also you can use options like :except and :only for `to_json` method.

```
Result.find(passed_id).attributes.to_json(:only => ['status', 'message'])
```

Comment: It was just a yaml dump of the object. I am actually passing the request as json. thats determined in the URL as add.json

Comment: Your answer was first but the problems already been fixed so no need to leave it open.

Answer (score 4):

```
record.serializable_hash
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.12/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html#method-i-serializable_hash

I write something more because SO ask me to do so.